# Encoding error while fetching HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x

On Python3.2 I am getting following error when trying to get HTML from remote site, it works well on Python 2.7

[image]

Code:

```
def connectAmazon():
    usleep = lambda x: sleep(x/1000000.0)
    factor = 400
    shouldRetry = True
    retries = 0
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36'}
    attempt = 0
    while shouldRetry == True:
        random = randint(2, 9)
        attempt += 1
        print ("Attempt#", attempt)
        #print (attempt)
        url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B009OZUPUC/sr=/qid=/ref=olp_prime_new?ie=UTF8&colid=&coliid=&condition=new&me=&qid=&seller=&shipPromoFilter=1&sort=sip&sr"
        html = requests.get(url)
        status = html.status_code
        if status == 200:
            shouldRetry = False
            print ("Success. Check HTML Below")
            print(html.text) #The Buggy Line
            break
        elif status == 503:
            retries += 1
            delay = random * (pow(retries, 4)*100)
            print ("Delay(ms) = ", delay)
            #print (delay)
            usleep(delay)
            shouldRetry = True


connectAmazon()
```

What to be done to resolve this on Python 3.2 or Py 3.x?

Comment: It would help to some some actual code. Specially the one dealing with the output.

Comment: General tip: We **HATE** screenshots of errors. they're not searchable. It's a windows command prompt. you can mark/copy the text contents of the window by clicking the little 'cmd' icon in the top left and selecting the various options under the "edit" sub-menu.

Comment: @MarcB it was sent by one of the devs as I can't produce the result on my machine.. I asked him to send text though.

Comment: @PauloBu Question updated with Code

Comment: @Volatil3 and you say that works on Python2? Can you tell me `html.text` what type it is both in Python2 and Python3? They are probably `unicode` and `str` respectively but just to make sure.

Comment: Py 2 sends of type `'unicide`. No access Py3 at the moment.

Comment: That code seems Python3 because `print()` is with parenthesis. That should fail in Python2 unless you're importing `print_function` from `__future__`.

Comment: The line gives no error in Python2.7 other than it prints parenthesis instead.

Comment: Is this encoding error because of parenthesis?

Comment: No, I don't know how are you running this on Py2 because it seems definitely Py3. The encoding error is because when outputting, `print` is encoding `html.text` into the `cmd` encoding (you can know which one it is by issuing command `chcp`). There is probably one char in `html.text` than can't be encoded in `cmd`'s encoding, hence the problem. I can't provide an answer because I still don't know for sure which target version you want it.

Comment: My target version is 3.2. And print() works in Python 2.7

Comment: @PauloBu chcp command returns Active Code page to 437

Comment: Yes, that's the usual one. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Windows Command Line is very problematic with encodings<sup>*</sup>. The encoding error is because when outputting, `print` is encoding `html.text` into the `cmd` encoding (you can know which one it is by issuing command chcp). There is probably one char in `html.text` than can't be encoded in `cmd`'s encoding.

My solution for Python3 would be forcing an output encoding. Sadly, in Python3 this is a little more problematic than I would like. You'll need to replace the line `print(html.text)` for:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(html.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Of course, that line won't work in Python2. In Python2 you can just `encode` your output before printing it so `print(html.text)` can be replaced with:

```
print html.text.encode('utf8')
```

**Important note:** In Python2 `print` is a keyword, not a function. So calling `print('hi')` works because `print` is printing the expression inside the parenthesis. When you do `print('hi',2)` you'll get the tuple `('hi',2)` outputted. That's not exactly what you want. It works by miracle :D

Hope this helps!

<sub>* This is due to its lack of support to `utf8`. They have a weird `650001` code page which is not entirely the same as `utf-8` and Python does not work with it.</sub>

Comment: I believe your suggested code is for 3.x only because on 2.7 I get `'AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'buffer'`

Comment: I explained in the answer: _"Of course, that line won't work in Python2"_. I gave example for both versions. For Python2 you do the second example: `print html.text.encode('utf8')`. The two version handle strings differently so having just one method for both would be complicated. You can test for a Python version with `sys.version`.

Comment: `sys.version_info` also gives information about the version with a better format (`tuple`). You can perform version comparisons with `if sys.version_info < (3,0) #python2`